# Putting then immediately removing value from channel causes weird behavior (ClojureScript core.async)

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, core.async

The following is a contrived example for learning purposes. It involves jamming the value `"val"` into a channel and then immediately removing it within a go block:

```
(def test-chan1 (chan))

(go 
  (println 
    (<! 
      (go 
        (do 
          (>! test-chan1 "val") 
          (<! test-chan1)))))) ; the return value of the (do..) is "val" 
                               ; ...hence the return value of the nested go block should be a channel containing "val"
                               ; hence (println ..) should eventually print "val" to the console
```

**Question:** Why does this code snippet not print "val" to the console?

Comment: Minor comment, you dont need the 'do'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Channels by default are synchronous, so a put will block until there is somebody to get (and the other way around).

So Your problem is that the inner `go` is blocked on the put (`>!`) forever. Try changing your channel to `(channel 1)`.

Comment: That worked -- but I am completely confused as to why :( Aren't we taking via `(<!)` immediately after the `(>!)`? Why doesn't this cause the go block to stop blocking?

Comment: Is that you would have to `(<! .. (>! ..)` within the same s-expression in order for it to stop blocking the go block?

Comment: The `(<!)` expression is never run as the go block is blocked in the `(>!)`

Comment: Until something takes the value off the channel, `>!` is blocked (stuck). It never gets to the next line. You need another go block or thread to take from the channel. Adding the `1` parameter to the `chan` function gives it a buffer of 1, so that one value can be put on the channel without blocking the putter (though any further values will block their putters, until something takes from the channel).

Comment: Another way to put on the channel without blocking is by using the `put!` function instead of the `<!` function.